# Ripple effect is lost when inside another Component

Tags: reactjs

Ripple effect seems to be lost when I put a BaseComponent with a ripple effect inside a custom one.

I'm creating a generic Component in react that looks like this:

```
const ToggleButton = ({ selected, items, onChange, ...props }) => {
const classes = useStyles();
const tabsStyles = appleTabsStylesHook.useTabs();
const tabItemStyles = appleTabsStylesHook.useTabItem();

const handleChangeData = (event, data) => {
    onChange(data);
};

return (
    <Fragment>
        {items && (
            <Tabs
                className={classes.root}
                classes={tabsStyles}
                value={selected}
                onChange={handleChangeData}
                indicatorColor='primary'
                textColor='primary'
                centered
            >
                {items.map(({ label, value }) => (
                    <Tab
                        classes={tabItemStyles}
                        key={`toggle-${value}`}
                        value={value}
                        label={label}
                    />
                ))}
            </Tabs>
        )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

When I call it directly from any Component, it looks like this:

[image]

This is the return statement I used to call the `ToggleButton`:

```
return (
    <ToggleButton
        {...props}
        onChange={handleChangeData}
        selected={searchMode}
        items={[
            {
                label: t('common.search.basic'),
                value: 'basic',
            },
            {
                label: t('common.search.advanced'),
                value: 'advanced',
            },
        ]}
    />
);
```

Then I tried to insert it in another Component I created like this:

**The return statement:**

```
return <TestContent />;
```

The new Component:

```
const TestContent = () => {
    return (
        <ToggleButton
            onChange={handleChangeData}
            selected={searchMode}
            items={[
                {
                    label: t('common.search.basic'),
                    value: 'basic',
                },
                {
                    label: t('common.search.advanced'),
                    value: 'advanced',
                },
            ]}
        />
    );
};
```

So I just encapsulated the `ToggleButton` with a new `Component` I just created. But then the tab effect is lost as seen here:

[image]

Why is this effect being lost if I encapsulate it in a custom Component? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Since Tab is a composed component, the library internally will be adding additional props to the children which are meant to reach the Tab component. Now that you have an additional component wrapper over it, it is passed on to that wrapper and since you do not forward these props, it doesn't reach the Tab component causing the animation effect to not work properly

You can just forward the props to solve this

```
const TestContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <ToggleButton
            {...props}
            onChange={handleChangeData}
            selected={searchMode}
            items={[
                {
                    label: t('common.search.basic'),
                    value: 'basic',
                },
                {
                    label: t('common.search.advanced'),
                    value: 'advanced',
                },
            ]}
        />
    );
};
```

Comment: How do I call it then?

`return <TestContent />;` Because I changed the code to be like that but the effect is still not working...

Comment: You will call it like `return <TestContent {...props}/>;`

Comment: Actually this didn't solve my issue yet. That's why I didn't close the question.